# Haxe defines with dot

Tags: haxe, conditional-compilation

In Haxe, what is the correct way to refer to a define with a dot?

For example, for the library `thx.core`, how to write conditional compilation against the library name?

```
#if thx.core

#end
```

Furthermore, are there general rules for special characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `#if flag` syntax does not seem to handle dots.
However, `Compiler.getDefine()` handles most characters, including the dot:

hxml/build command: `-D é'"(-è_.çà)=test`

```
#if "é'\"(-è_çà)"
trace('will always be called, even without the -D');
#end

trace(haxe.macro.Compiler.getDefine("é'\"(-è_.çà)")); // test
```

There is a workaround for dots with initialization macros, even if it is not really pretty:

build.hxml

```
-x Main.hx
-D abc.def
--macro Macro.parseDefines()
```

Macro.hx

```
import haxe.macro.Compiler;

class Macro {
    public static macro function parseDefines():Void {
        if (Compiler.getDefine("abc.def") != null) {
            Compiler.define("abc_def");
        }
    }
}
```

Main.hx

```
class Main {
    public static function main() {
        #if abc_def
        trace("abc.def is defined!");
        #end
    }
}
```

Comment: `#if "whatever_string"` is always true, even there is no `-D whatever_string`

Comment: You're right, I did not test correctly with the `#if flag` syntax. I edited my answer with a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

[Starting with Haxe 4.0.0-rc.2](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/pull/8005), defines with a dot are permitted in `#if` as long as they are surrounded by parens:

```
#if (thx.core)

#end
```

`#if thx.core` without parens [will likely also work in the future](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/issues/8032).

Answer (score 0):

In the case of `thx.core`, you can use `thx_core` (with an underscore):

```
#if thx_core

#end
```

As far as I know there is no general support for special characters other than hyphens ([those get translated into underscores by the compiler](https://haxe.org/manual/lf-condition-compilation.html)).

The `thx.core` library [defines `-D thx_core`](https://github.com/fponticelli/thx.core/blob/master/extraParams.hxml) itself, using haxelib's [support for `extraParams.hxml`](https://haxe.org/manual/haxelib-extraParams.html) .